# avoid usage of str() in numba optimized functions

Tags: python, numba

In the following code snippet, I would like to avoid the usage of `str()` in the function foo.

```
import numpy as np

def foo(a):
    for runner in range(a.shape[0]):
        row = a[runner, :]
        toPrint = str(runner) + ' '+ str(row)
        print(toPrint)

myArray = np.array(np.arange(9).reshape(3,-1)).astype('float')

foo(myArray)
```

output:

```
0 [0. 1. 2.]
1 [3. 4. 5.]
2 [6. 7. 8.]
```

Background: I use numba (https://numba.pydata.org/ ) where the usage of `str()` in numba optimized functions is not possible.

How does the code of `foo` have to look like, if no usage of `str()` is allowed? Namely, no imports should happen (as numba most the times does not work with them).

Comment: I think the simple answer is don't print in that function. Can you return the value and print it in the calling function?

Comment: Adding to the comment of @PaulRooney, you're printing in a loop so maybe `yield` will work instead of `return`.

Comment: Maybe you can append it to a list before printing it out? If you really want to view it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider string formatting:

```
toPrint = '{} {}'.format(runner, row)
print(toPrint)
```

Or simply (because there's a space separating the arguments by default):

```
print(runner, row)

#  or [if you want to keep the toPrint variable]:

toPrint = (runner, row)
print(*toPrint)
```

Comment: The format will implicitly call `str` anyway, so it likely won't work.

Comment: yes, @iz_ is right, format will not work with numba, unfortunately. Printing though works.

Comment: Unfortunately, `print` will also call one of `str` or `repr`.

Answer (score 1):

If you would not like to use the `str()` function in the function foo, why not append the results into a temporary list first before printing them out?

```
import numpy as np
list1 = []

def foo(a):
    for runner in range(a.shape[0]):
        row = a[runner, :]
        toPrint = str(runner) + ' '+ str(row)
        list1.append(toPrint)

myArray = np.array(np.arange(9).reshape(3,-1)).astype('float')

foo(myArray)
print(list1)
```